# Is there anything I can do to modify colors of a check box with css?

Tags: html, css

I have a check box like this: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CmryF/)

```
<input type="checkbox" value="False" id="abc">

and in my css file:

#abc { background-color: Red; }
```

I want to modify it to make it so that when it's checked it becomes more visible, the background changes or I get a very thin border around the outside. But is seems like almost no css properties apply to this checkbox. I can't even change the height or size of font?

Can some person give me advice how I can change things with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's browser-specific. You won't see anything in FF or Chrome, but you will on Opera, for example. Generally the background color and border are the styles you can effect if it's a browser that supports it, but I don't have an exhaustive list off the top of my head if there are more.

Comment: But can I even change the size of the checkbox ?

Comment: Yes, you can set height and width on it but while that will resize it in Opera, it will actually move/position it in other browsers. Because it's so poorly supported, I wouldn't bother with it.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do much with the check box itself other than tweaking its `opacity` (e.g. start it from 0.8 and make it 1 when checked, so that it becomes more prominent).

However, you can achieve much more if you wrap the check box inside some other element (a `<label>` is both the natural choice and very practical) and styling that one instead.

**See a live example of this in [an update to your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CmryF/4/).**

Comment: Agreed - styling the label is a much better way to go.

Comment: I tried to tweak opacity of the checkbox and viewing with firefox but it seems not to work

Answer (score 0):

It depends a lot on what you actually want to do.

If you want a kind of highlight for the checkbox input as such, you might style the label/text/wrapping element instead of the checkbox itself, i.e.:

```
<label id="abc"><input type="checkbox" value="False" id="abc" />Bla</label>
```

If you want to style the actual checkmark box, you may need to use a kind of skinning as shown here for example:

http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/

Anyway this issue might heavily depend on the browser.

Answer (score 0):

The best way for you to do this effectively and **across all browsers** is to actually hide the checkbox and create a clickable element that toggles the hidden field value in javascript. There is a [jQuery UI button method](http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#checkbox) of doing this.

Alternatively, here's some jQuery Pseudocode if yo want to get you started if you want to do it yourself:

```
<input type="hidden" name="terms" value="off" class="checkbox"/>
<span class="toggler off">Toggle Text, image, or just blank</span>

$('.toggler').click(function() {
    $input =  $(this).closest('input.checkbox');
    if($(this).hasClass('off')) {
        $input.val('on');
        $(this).removeClass('off');
    } else {
        $input.val('off');
        $(this).addClass('off');
    }
});
```

Get this working correctly and it will look/work the same across all browsers.